# mariadb change own password without root permissions

Tags: mariadb, passwords, access-denied, change-password

I want to change the password of a user (with limited rights) on MariaDB without having to login on root user

I tried:

```
ALTER USER CURRENT_USER() IDENTIFIED BY 'newpassword';
```

-> Error: #1227 access denied; you need (at least one of) the CREATE USER privilege(s) for this operation

question: which grant do i need to perform so this user can change his own password (but not the password of other users). also this user shouldn´t be able to create other users either

Answer (score -1):

the solution i came up with is:
create a stored procedure which checks for you host and username and changes password for that user like:

```
delimiter %%
CREATE PROCEDURE alter_password(newpassword varchar(50))
BEGIN
declare username varchar(256);
declare hostname varchar(256);

SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(USER(),'@',1) INTO username;
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(USER(),'@',-1) INTO hostname;

 SET @A := CONCAT('SET PASSWORD FOR ''', username,'''@''%'' = PASSWORD(''', newpassword, ''');');
    PREPARE alter_user_stmt FROM @A;
    EXECUTE alter_user_stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE alter_user_stmt;
END;
%%
```

You create this procedure by logging in as a user with sufficient privileges (such as the root user)
then u grant execute rights for the user on that procedure with:

```
GRANT EXECUTE ON PROCEDURE alter_password TO 'username'@'hostname';
```

maybe u can use prepared statements for this if you want to automate it
then the user 'username'@'hostname' can edit his own password without having to give them any other administrative privileges by:

```
CALL alter_password('otherpassword');
```